# EXT-GWT (GXT) Display Icon and Text for displayfield in Combobox

Tags: gwt, combobox, gxt

Does anyone know how to display an Icon and a Text for the displaying field in ext-gwts combobo? I tried everything.

In the third `ComboBox` of this example ([klick me](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#combobox)) there is an icon and the text for the selectable values. This was no problem with the example template. But i want to show the icon and the text for the selected value too. How can i manage this?

I have a Model class for the icon and the text.

```java
public class Language extends DbBaseObjectModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8477520184310335811L;

public Language(String langIcon, String langName) {
    setLangIcon(langIcon);
    setLangName(langName);
}

public String getLangIcon() {
    return get("langIcon");
}

public String getLangName() {
    return get("langName");
}

public void setLangIcon(String langIcon) {
    set("langIcon", langIcon);
}

public void setLangName(String langName) {
    set("langName", langName);
}
}
```

This is how i initalize the ComboBox. I want to change the displayField "langName".

```java
final ListStore<Language> countries = new ListStore<Language>();
final Language german = new Language("de_DE", "Deutsch");
final Language english = new Language("en_GB", "Englisch");
countries.add(german);
countries.add(english);

final ComboBox<Language> combo = new ComboBox<Language>();
combo.setWidth(100);
combo.setStore(countries);
combo.setDisplayField("langName");
combo.setTemplate(getFlagTemplate());
combo.setTypeAhead(true);
combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
combo.setValue(german);
```

This is the template for the `ComboBox` two show the selectable values.

```java
private native String getFlagTemplate() /*-{
    return [ '<tpl for=".">', '<div class="x-combo-list-item">',
            '<img src="resources/images/lang/{langIcon}.png">',
            ' {langName}</div>', '</tpl>' ].join("");
}-*/;
```

How can i use an template for the displayField or is there an other possibility?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.ListModelPropertyEditor`.

The `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.PropertyEditor#getStringValue` returns the string that should be displayed and the `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.PropertyEditor#convertStringValue` converts the displayed string back into the model.

This isn't a very performant implementation but it works:

```
public class TemplateModelPropertyEditor<D extends ModelData> extends
        ListModelPropertyEditor<D> {

    /** Template to render the model. */
    private XTemplate template;

    @Override
    public D convertStringValue(final String value) {
        for (final D d : models) {
            final String val = getStringValue(d);
            if (value.equals(val)) {
                return d;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStringValue(final D value) {
        if (template != null) {
            final Element div = DOM.createDiv();
            template.overwrite(div, Util.getJsObject(value));
            return div.getInnerText();
        }
        final Object obj = value.get(displayProperty);
        if (obj != null) {
            return obj.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setSimpleTemplate(final String html) {
        template = XTemplate.create(html);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TemplateModelPropertyEditor<Language> propertyEditor = new TemplateModelPropertyEditor<Language>();
propertyEditor.setSimpleTemplate(getFlagTemplate());
combo.setPropertyEditor(propertyEditor);
```

Comment: There is still a mistake! But i don't know what kind of mistake. Everything works fine, but the icon won't be displayed. Look at my post above.

Answer (score 0):

which imports?

I added these ones:

```
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.XTemplate;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.util.Util;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.ListModelPropertyEditor;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
```

Everthing works fine, but it don't display an icon. When i debug the return div.getInnerText() method throws an error called: Method "getInnerText" with signature "()Ljava/lang/String;" is not applicable on this object.

The created div element looks okay

```
<DIV><DIV class=x-combo-list-item><IMG src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/resources/images/lang/de_DE.png"> Deutsch</DIV></DIV>
```